SVG mask is not being applied through style tag
What I am trying to do is make the below SVG into a mask. The reason is, all the white space will be transparent, and all the black space can have a pattern applied to it. I'll make a mask, then apply the mask-composite: exclude; CSS rule, but for the time being, the mask isn't even being applied.
Original SVG:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="667.8" height="667.8" viewBox="0 0 667.8 667.8" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(2.9934205851 0 0 2.9934205851 333.9 333.9)" id="1"  >
<path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: evenodd; opacity: 1;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  paint-order="stroke"  transform=" translate(-240.00096, -123.51984)" d="M 0 0.16032 C 144.6048 0.16032 289.24992 0.16032 433.85472 0.16032 C 433.44671999999997 1.57536 433.19712 0.61152 433.85472 2.0496 C 434.96544 2.0544 437.79744 3.86496 440.28384 5.8271999999999995 C 440.15904 6.70848 440.03136 7.590719999999999 439.90656 8.472 C 441.41856 8.34624 442.93248 8.22048 444.44544 8.094719999999999 C 444.57024 9.1008 444.696 10.108799999999999 444.82368 11.115839999999999 C 446.45376000000005 10.90176 446.93088 11.26752 447.47232 12.2496 C 448.85760000000005 11.999039999999999 450.24576 11.746559999999999 451.63104000000004 11.494079999999999 C 451.75776 10.486079999999998 451.88256000000007 9.478079999999999 452.00928000000005 8.471039999999999 C 454.76544000000007 8.337599999999998 456.32640000000004 8.517119999999998 457.68384000000003 9.603839999999998 C 457.38912000000005 10.938239999999999 457.65888 11.947199999999999 457.3056 13.382399999999999 C 459.57120000000003 13.36896 460.04256000000004 13.94976 461.46528 14.892479999999999 C 461.088 19.39584 462.21504 17.67936 462.22272 22.45056 C 461.1696 22.63968 462.1968 22.4256 461.46528 23.20608 C 460.45728 23.07936 459.44736 22.95264 458.43936 22.82688 C 457.43232 22.70208 456.42240000000004 22.57536 455.4144 22.4496 C 455.52096 25.5888 455.18112 26.01024 455.03424 27.36096 C 451.87008000000003 27.365759999999998 450.96000000000004 28.40352 450.87456000000003 29.62848 C 449.60256000000004 30.65472 450.21888 31.32864 450.49632 34.91712 C 449.11104 35.295359999999995 447.72192 35.672639999999994 446.3376 36.05184 C 446.30208 38.495999999999995 446.43456000000003 38.38848 446.71488 38.695679999999996 C 448.65504 43.16448 454.76448 48.68639999999999 457.6848 51.541439999999994 C 458.81856 51.288959999999996 459.9552 51.03744 461.08992 50.78592 C 461.01792 52.711679999999994 461.28768 50.75712 461.4672 52.6752 C 459.76896 52.79615999999999 457.74528 56.69087999999999 460.33344 58.343039999999995 C 460.41504 59.29248 464.4864 62.35104 464.8704 62.49983999999999 C 464.59104 64.1904 463.88448 63.71903999999999 464.8704 65.90111999999999 C 468.69408000000004 65.89247999999999 467.02272 67.83935999999999 469.41024000000004 68.54495999999999 C 470.78976000000006 69.83903999999998 473.46624 68.48736 474.32736000000006 67.78847999999999 C 475.55424000000005 69.17952 475.1030400000001 70.13184 476.97504000000004 70.056 C 477.79008000000005 70.16256 478.06176000000005 69.19584 479.24544000000003 70.43424 C 480.0192 71.11488 479.51328 70.43903999999999 480.00192000000004 71.56704 C 477.83808000000005 71.73312 478.48800000000006 101.45760000000001 478.48800000000006 113.50656000000001 C 478.36320000000006 157.45632 478.23552000000007 201.4176 478.1107200000001 245.36832 C 319.0099200000001 245.87136 159.86016000000006 246.37632000000002 0.7574400000000878 246.87936000000002 C 0.5068800000000878 164.64864 0.2534400000000878 82.39200000000002 0.0009600000000877795 0.1603200000000129 z" stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.3997191152 0 0 0.3997191152 333.9 333.9)" id="2"  >
<g style="" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  paint-order="stroke"   >
        <g transform="matrix(1.1350609626 0 0 1.1350609626 0 0)"  >
<path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  paint-order="stroke"  transform=" translate(-192.0004181771, -191.9998936552)" d="M 383.043466667 158.570133333 C 383.035866667 158.562533333 383.0204 158.547066667 383.0052 158.531866667 C 382.1148 157.512133333 377.9372 155.929333333 375.220533333 154.734666667 C 374.5508 154.445466667 373.964933333 154.171466667 373.546266667 153.9432 C 373.3636 153.844133333 373.211733333 153.745466667 373.0976 153.6616 C 371.598266667 152.573466667 359.057333333 143.434266667 357.1476 141.6612 C 356.013733333 140.6188 355.0776 137.9856 354.187066667 135.253733333 C 353.578533333 133.374266667 352.9848 131.441333333 352.376266667 129.934533333 C 351.2424 127.1648 342.019333333 121.853066667 336.0608 118.17 C 335.543466667 117.842666667 335.0412 117.5308 334.577066667 117.241733333 C 335.703333333 115.1108 336.7004 111.306 332.301733333 107.942533333 C 328.436 104.99 323.17 106.184666667 319.5024 107.668533333 C 318.4672 107.379466667 317.478 107.158666667 316.656 107.029466667 C 315.8952 106.907733333 315.096133333 107.021866667 314.2896 107.318533333 C 309.3128 108.1708 300.607333333 109.723066667 294.435733333 111.389866667 C 288.0816 113.117066667 262.535866667 108.010933333 257.186266667 106.8468 C 252.0952 102.471333333 244.501066667 97.9282666666 236.0768 98.6892 C 226.831333333 99.5338666666 213.377333333 100.371066667 202.617066667 100.036133333 C 191.864666667 99.7013333333 175.724266667 97.6845333333 170.678933333 96.1704 C 165.634 94.656 159.637466667 93.7277333333 159.637466667 93.7277333333 C 149.326133333 91.9090666666 132.3488 92.5176 123.253066667 91.7109333333 C 114.1572 90.8969333333 104.657333333 92.5176 93.1362666666 99.998 C 81.6150666666 107.4784 70.2950666666 114.35 62.2102666667 119.2048 C 54.1258666667 124.06 43.6146666667 135.9844 41.39 147.7108 C 39.1665333333 159.437466667 38.1577333333 168.941866667 34.3169333333 179.4588 C 30.4762666667 189.968533333 28.8585333333 198.661733333 28.0505333333 207.558 C 27.2413333333 216.454666667 29.6666666667 216.454666667 26.4317333333 221.3084 C 23.1984 226.159333333 19.5594666667 231.821066667 16.326 237.0784 C 13.0912 242.333866667 9.6548 244.5596 5.0068 245.367733333 C 0.357866666667 246.176133333 -0.653466666667 248.3996 0.357866666667 254.060933333 C 1.36933333333 259.7212 3.18653333333 268.416 2.98546666667 274.076266667 C 2.78213333333 279.7376 8.64346666666 286.8148 10.8676 288.634266667 C 13.0912 290.453733333 22.9954666667 291.465066667 25.4218666667 291.061066667 C 27.8472 290.657066667 29.0593333333 286.8148 28.2512 283.780933333 C 27.4432 280.748933333 29.2876 277.284266667 31.1369333333 274.761866667 C 32.9842666667 272.239733333 37.0197333333 271.902933333 37.0197333333 271.902933333 L 38.5326666667 273.248133333 C 38.5326666667 273.248133333 40.3828 272.408 41.896 270.052933333 C 43.4097333333 267.700133333 44.0817333333 266.522133333 44.0817333333 266.522133333 L 44.0817333333 269.045333333 C 44.0817333333 269.045333333 46.6026666667 266.690266667 47.7808 265.512133333 C 48.9565333333 264.3364 49.9661333333 262.823066667 49.9661333333 262.823066667 L 49.7982666667 266.018266667 C 49.7982666667 266.018266667 52.8238666667 264.6728 55.1765333333 262.4852 C 57.532 260.299466667 60.5574666667 256.9368 60.5574666667 256.9368 L 59.5490666667 260.635866667 C 59.5490666667 260.635866667 63.752 258.786933333 65.4322666667 256.9368 C 67.1142666666 255.087466667 69.4692 252.900666667 69.4692 252.900666667 L 70.6450666666 255.759466667 C 70.6450666666 255.759466667 74.3433333333 252.564266667 76.0248 251.722533333 C 77.492 250.988933333 78.5748 250.1276 78.8262666666 249.919733333 C 80.1966666666 252.4044 83.2618666666 258.566933333 84.5638666666 261.753866667 C 86.2821333333 265.951333333 88.8589333333 266.499066667 88.1714666666 270.332266667 C 87.4844 274.165733333 85.0798666666 284.752666667 88.8589333333 288.586266667 C 92.6354666666 292.417866667 119.596 290.7764 127.667466667 290.957466667 C 135.7428 291.1408 145.011466667 289.499333333 145.696666667 287.854133333 C 146.389066667 286.213066667 147.591333333 279.460133333 141.2296 277.2676 C 134.883066667 275.077466667 130.583466667 270.880266667 128.010666667 266.3172 C 125.435733333 261.753866667 124.404666667 255.546266667 125.091733333 250.8012 C 125.778133333 246.0548 126.8092 239.301866667 127.667466667 237.294666667 C 127.8304 236.910266667 127.949066667 236.536 128.034933333 236.178133333 L 128.650533333 239.111066667 C 128.650533333 239.111066667 129.320266667 238.1012 131.002266667 237.260933333 C 132.683733333 236.4196 134.700533333 234.234 134.700533333 234.234 L 133.688266667 236.7576 L 133.186 237.260933333 C 133.186 237.260933333 135.88 236.3648 136.884266667 235.691333333 C 137.8964 235.019333333 139.578266667 233.2248 139.578266667 233.2248 C 139.578266667 233.2248 139.799066667 234.906 139.464133333 235.243866667 C 139.129333333 235.579466667 138.566133333 236.476 138.566133333 236.476 C 138.566133333 236.476 141.0316 236.027733333 142.934133333 234.681466667 C 144.844 233.337466667 147.081466667 231.543333333 147.081466667 231.543333333 C 147.081466667 231.543333333 147.423866667 233.2248 147.081466667 233.673866667 C 146.746533333 234.120533333 146.2976 234.570266667 146.2976 234.570266667 C 146.2976 234.570266667 150.224133333 233.562 151.5712 232.103466667 C 152.910666667 230.6468 154.478 229.189466667 154.478 229.189466667 L 154.8204 231.767866667 C 154.8204 231.767866667 158.6328 231.3188 160.0864 229.861466667 C 161.54 228.4048 163.2216 227.956133333 163.2216 227.956133333 C 163.2216 227.956133333 164.682666667 231.878933333 163.784666667 234.009466667 C 162.886666667 236.1404 162.772533333 238.0464 162.772533333 238.0464 L 163.670533333 236.925733333 C 163.670533333 236.925733333 163.670533333 239.6164 163.114933333 241.858 C 162.551866667 244.1008 162.217333333 246.117866667 162.217333333 246.117866667 L 163.564 244.324533333 C 163.564 244.324533333 162.886666667 247.6864 161.988666667 251.1624 C 161.098533333 254.638533333 160.0864 258.226 160.0864 258.226 L 161.54 256.095066667 C 161.54 256.095066667 160.0864 263.270133333 160.3072 266.746533333 C 160.535466667 270.221066667 161.319333333 273.5852 161.319333333 273.5852 L 162.217333333 270.894666667 C 162.217333333 270.894666667 162.666 272.6872 164.1196 275.714666667 C 165.580666667 278.741733333 166.250133333 280.7588 166.250133333 280.7588 L 167.262266667 277.5088 C 167.262266667 277.5088 168.495066667 277.8452 168.936533333 281.3212 C 169.3932 284.796133333 170.618133333 287.3756 173.7612 288.7196 C 176.896266667 290.0648 184.970133333 292.419466667 187.656533333 291.859333333 C 190.350266667 291.2984 207.274266667 293.2048 208.058133333 288.832266667 C 208.842 284.459733333 206.041333333 280.7588 204.474 280.7588 C 202.898666667 280.7588 200.6616 281.3212 200.775733333 279.302533333 C 200.881866667 277.284266667 200.4332 267.418533333 202.4496 263.3836 C 204.474 259.346666667 208.058133333 250.266266667 209.853733333 246.789866667 C 211.642266667 243.315466667 212.319466667 240.735866667 212.319466667 240.735866667 C 212.319466667 240.735866667 213.103333333 242.418933333 212.9892 242.8664 C 212.875066667 243.315466667 212.540266667 244.549733333 212.540266667 244.549733333 C 212.540266667 244.549733333 213.658933333 242.979733333 214.6708 241.184933333 C 215.675333333 239.391866667 216.915733333 237.932933333 216.915733333 237.932933333 L 216.687466667 240.735866667 C 216.687466667 240.735866667 218.140666667 239.503733333 219.3736 237.596533333 C 220.606533333 235.691333333 222.0676 234.570266667 222.0676 234.570266667 L 221.7328 237.821866667 C 221.7328 237.821866667 222.737066667 236.251466667 224.753733333 233.898266667 C 226.778133333 231.543333333 228.010533333 230.422266667 228.010533333 230.422266667 L 227.112533333 233.898266667 C 227.112533333 233.898266667 231.0316 233.001866667 232.2644 230.3104 C 233.497333333 227.619733333 235.856133333 224.4812 235.856133333 224.4812 L 235.962666667 226.3876 L 238.428533333 221.901733333 C 238.428533333 221.901733333 238.945866667 223.508 239.653466667 225.2012 C 238.1772 228.87 237.431466667 230.8112 237.865333333 230.1596 C 238.436 229.296 239.288266667 228.074133333 240.300533333 226.650266667 C 240.361333333 226.784933333 240.429733333 226.9172 240.498133333 227.0476 C 240.536266667 228.803866667 240.734 231.49 241.457066667 233.811733333 C 242.651733333 237.64 244.326 239.435333333 244.326 239.435333333 L 244.211866667 235.605866667 C 244.211866667 235.605866667 245.5208 240.512933333 246.723066667 243.383066667 C 247.917733333 246.255866667 250.071333333 248.408 250.071333333 248.408 L 249.348266667 243.383066667 C 249.348266667 243.383066667 252.704133333 246.255866667 253.7772 249.7236 C 254.850133333 253.195066667 256.767866667 256.904 256.767866667 256.904 L 257.003733333 252.236933333 C 257.003733333 252.236933333 259.157333333 258.339466667 260.237866667 261.928 C 261.3108 265.517466667 264.6592 269.226266667 264.6592 269.226266667 L 264.545066667 265.277866667 C 264.545066667 265.277866667 267.170266667 268.867333333 270.161066667 272.456 C 273.151333333 276.045733333 275.1908 279.155466667 275.1908 279.155466667 C 275.1908 279.155466667 275.2592 277.106266667 275.343066667 276.311866667 C 275.678 277.127066667 276.2412 278.128266667 277.215066667 279.190666667 C 277.9532 280.007066667 278.8056 280.3064 279.733733333 280.370266667 C 280.372933333 280.944 281.058133333 281.5404 281.765733333 282.146266667 C 285.114 285.019066667 287.267466667 286.693066667 287.267466667 286.693066667 L 287.625066667 283.5828 C 287.625066667 283.5828 289.778666667 285.258 292.053866667 286.693066667 C 294.3216 288.128933333 298.6288 290.163066667 302.334666667 291.478666667 C 306.0484 292.795866667 319.205333333 292.554666667 324.585466667 292.1972 C 326.533466667 292.0672 328.5884 291.669866667 330.155733333 290.895066667 C 331.304666667 290.738266667 332.0508 290.539066667 332.240933333 290.2892 C 333.3596 288.832266667 333.0248 283.5632 330.4524 281.544133333 C 330.087333333 281.262666667 329.6156 280.974933333 329.06 280.6828 C 325.719333333 276.793733333 320.095733333 270.044533333 317.6228 267.333866667 C 314.137333333 261.288133333 309.7848 253.568933333 304.853733333 244.459066667 C 304.434933333 243.684666667 304.008933333 242.918133333 303.590133333 242.154266667 C 303.0728 240.968666667 302.608666667 239.8828 302.205333333 238.9428 C 301.5508 237.411066667 300.485733333 235.835733333 299.199466667 234.207466667 C 295.0904 226.6896 291.4832 219.538 289.664533333 212.158133333 C 287.031733333 201.5108 285.951066667 199.476666667 286.673733333 195.8872 C 286.757733333 195.451066667 286.803466667 194.986266667 286.826133333 194.501333333 C 287.1836 194.190933333 287.374133333 193.968 287.351066667 193.888266667 C 287.214266667 193.478533333 288.1656 195.5252 288.4396 196.7524 C 288.7132 197.98 288.5764 200.4332 288.5764 200.4332 C 288.5764 200.4332 289.527733333 198.797866667 291.026666667 196.8888 C 292.5336 194.979466667 295.120666667 193.615733333 295.120666667 193.615733333 L 294.161733333 197.570666667 C 294.161733333 197.570666667 296.62 196.343066667 299.207066667 193.615733333 C 301.802133333 190.89 302.753333333 190.070133333 302.753333333 190.070133333 C 302.753333333 190.070133333 303.841466667 191.433066667 304.115466667 192.796666667 C 304.3892 194.1604 304.8004 196.8888 304.8004 196.8888 C 304.8004 196.8888 306.299333333 194.1604 307.798266667 191.9788 C 309.2976 189.800266667 310.385733333 187.616133333 310.385733333 187.616133333 C 310.385733333 187.616133333 310.248933333 189.115466667 310.248933333 191.024533333 C 310.248933333 192.9332 311.344666667 194.2976 311.344666667 194.2976 C 311.344666667 194.2976 313.384 192.114933333 314.883066667 188.567466667 C 316.3824 185.029066667 316.3824 183.392933333 316.3824 183.392933333 C 316.3824 183.392933333 317.0672 185.432266667 318.018133333 187.205333333 C 318.977066667 188.978266667 321.1536 189.115466667 321.1536 189.115466667 C 321.1536 189.115466667 320.8872 187.753333333 320.7504 184.891866667 C 320.6132 182.0232 322.797333333 181.071866667 322.797333333 181.071866667 C 322.797333333 181.071866667 323.200666667 182.434 323.748266667 184.344133333 C 324.2888 186.254 324.2888 188.978266667 324.2888 188.978266667 C 324.2888 188.978266667 325.6584 186.528 327.697866667 184.755066667 C 329.044933333 183.590533333 329.562266667 181.726133333 329.76 180.5772 C 329.859066667 179.976133333 329.881733333 179.572933333 329.881733333 179.572933333 C 329.881733333 179.572933333 330.018933333 181.7492 330.429733333 184.070133333 C 330.833066667 186.3912 332.1952 187.342133333 332.1952 187.342133333 C 332.1952 187.342133333 332.4692 186.254 332.7432 185.158266667 C 333.0172 184.070133333 334.379333333 181.619866667 334.379333333 181.619866667 C 334.379333333 181.619866667 334.652933333 183.658933333 335.064133333 185.295066667 C 335.467466667 186.931333333 336.152266667 189.800266667 336.152266667 189.800266667 C 336.152266667 189.800266667 336.5632 189.252266667 338.602533333 186.931333333 C 340.6496 184.617866667 342.148533333 182.982 342.148533333 182.982 L 342.559733333 187.616133333 C 342.559733333 187.616133333 343.784666667 185.432266667 345.968933333 184.070133333 C 348.1452 182.708 349.918133333 182.8448 349.918133333 182.8448 L 349.2408 185.158266667 C 349.2408 185.158266667 353.6012 182.708 356.4628 181.7492 C 358.517333333 181.064266667 360.153466667 180.737066667 362.679733333 180.5544 C 363.6688 180.478133333 364.795066667 180.4252 366.142133333 180.387066667 C 370.913333333 180.249866667 374.048533333 174.8016 374.048533333 174.8016 C 374.048533333 174.8016 375.821866667 174.8016 377.7316 174.1164 C 377.769866667 174.1164 377.762266667 174.1164 377.7392 174.1164 C 379.390533333 173.507866667 379.6036 168.584266667 379.634266667 167.3212 C 379.641866667 167.130666667 379.641866667 167.024533333 379.641866667 167.024533333 C 379.641866667 167.024533333 380.319066667 166.6208 382.502933333 164.300266667 C 384.6792 161.9792 384.139066667 159.932266667 383.043466667 158.570133333" stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
        <g transform="matrix(2.4986444438 0 0 2.4986444438 -12.7691200265 -48.7990533798)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="default" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" paint-order="stroke"  ><tspan x="-57.900390625" y="5.0540140086" >Shane</tspan></text>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>



Masked SVG:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="667.8" height="667.8" viewBox="0 0 667.8 667.8" xml:space="preserve">

<style>
    #new_mask
    {
        mask: url(./new_test.svg) center/contain no-repeat, linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
        /*mask-composite: exclude;*/
    }
</style>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" id="#new_mask"></rect>

</svg>



Mask Composite:
As per this link, mask-composite is a suggestion.

so you want to have a see-through effect?

@TemaniAfif yes, 8 more characters to go. Maybe to better clarify, I want all white to be transparent, and all black to be able to have a filter applied to it, on the original SVG.

read this (long) answer and you will find what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78548682/8620333 (there is an example with background image)

Thank you, I will check it when I get home.

@TemaniAfif Thank you, I got it to work. I've noticed your presence on here and appreciate the time and effort you've put in and the valuable answers you've left behind.
